# some intersectRaySphere c procedure optymization through rewriting it to x86 asm (How?)

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, raytracing, fpu

Hullo, I've got not to much knowledge in assembly,
and i am thinking how to optimize it by rewriting this 
in x86 (32-bit fpu or sse2) assembly, thing should be
optimized - rewritten in correct assembly, then I will test if 
I've got some speed up (length() and dot() should be 
written in asm here also) This code is used by my 
simple real time ray-tracer and it works - but I am not much 
good in asm optimizations)

```
    inline float intersectRaySphere(float3* rO, float3* rV, float3* sO, float sR)
   {
    static float3 Q;

    Q = sub(sO,rO);
    float c = length(&Q);
    float v = dot(&Q,rV);
    float d = sR*sR - (c*c - v*v);

    // If there was no intersection, return -1
    if (d < 0.0) return (-1.0f);

    // Return the distance to the [first] intersecting point
    return (v - sqrt(d));
    }
```

Thank You in Advance

//edits

```
    struct float3
    {
     float x;
     float y;
     float z;
    };


    inline float length(float3* v) {
     return sqrt( (v->x)*(v->x) + (v->y)*(v->y) + (v->z)*(v->z) );
    }

   inline float dot(float3* a, float3* b) {
     return (*a).x * (*b).x + (*a).y * (*b).y + (*a).z * (*b).z;
   }
```

and demo exe (unoptymized in not even so much optymized c):

dl.dropbox.com/u/42887985/re29.zip

Maybe someone could give me a somewhat good fpu asm routines for length 
dot (or normalize not shown here) ?? Though whole procedure for intersect
procedure would be the best ;-)

Comment: You also need to show the code for `sub`, `length` and `dot`, and the typedef for `float3`.

Comment: Unless there is a real need to, you should be using SSE intrinsics instead of assembly. In any case, I can already see that this isn't gonna turn out well because you have that function encapsulation. If you want real speed, you'll need to approach this from a slightly higher level.

Comment: Is it acceptable to return the squared distance?

Comment: @paul float3 is `struct (float x,y,z}` dot is obvious also length `inline float length(float3* v) {  return sqrt( (v->x)*(v->x) + (v->y)*(v->y) + (v->z)*(v->z) ); }` @mystical I want to rewrite it to fpu x86 assembly, then the second version also sse2 (l8er maybe avx) - need helb, i wasnt coding x86 asm long time

Comment: @harold it is not squared i think (not sure because i am not involved in such geometry to deep) It works, by now it is [link](dl.dropbox.com/u/42887985/re29.zip) but i want to optymize some functions with assembly by hand - need some help with that ;-) How the procedure would look like in asm

Comment: @user982377 I know it *isn't* squared, but *can* it be? What are you doing with the result? Probably just comparing it, right? You could rid of both the square roots that way (the one in length is trivial to remove since you use the squared length anyway). Square roots are slow.

Comment: @user982377: please edit your question to include the additional information - it's unreadable in comments.

Comment: @harald - ye I have four balls on the scene for each pixel i count this intersection distance then I get closest one, then count normal on the closest ball and put some color to pixel - It can be some minor optymization not to count square I will rethink it - but I would like some much involving myself in asm here - whole procedure rewrital in asm is what i would like very much (even if it will show that it is no speed up - for my own learning)

Comment: So for learning, ok, but then how does it help if we just post the answer? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @harold im readin in parrallel but some posting would help me, reading about fpu is a few day quest, at least, and i am not sure if i go through it - some specific help with such soubroutine would speed me up ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a "nice" function to convert to SSE. Almost nothing is actually parallel. So let's change the function to intersect 4 rays at once. And it would help if the rays were stores in [SOA (struct of arrays)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array) instead of AOS (array of structs) as well.

With those changes, it might become something like this (not tested in any way):

```
inline void intersect4RaysSphere(
 float* rOx, float* rOy, float* rOz,
 float* rVx, float* rVy, float* rVz,
 float sOx, float sOy, float sOz,
 float sR)
{
    // calculate Q
    movss xmm0, sOx
    movss xmm1, sOy
    movss xmm2, sOz
    shufps xmm0, xmm0, 0
    shufps xmm1, xmm1, 0
    shufps xmm2, xmm2, 0
    subps xmm0, [rOx]
    subps xmm1, [rOy]
    subps xmm2, [rOz]
    // calculate pow(dot(Q, rV), 2) in xmm3
    movaps xmm3, [rVx]
    movaps xmm4, [rVy]
    movaps xmm5, [rVz]
    mulps xmm3, xmm0
    mulps xmm4, xmm1
    mulps xmm5, xmm2
    addps xmm3, xmm4
    addps xmm3, xmm5
    movaps xmm4, xmm3
    mulps xmm3, xmm3
    // calculate pow(length(Q), 2)
    // there's no point in taking the square root only to then square it
    mulps xmm0, xmm0
    mulps xmm1, xmm1
    mulps xmm2, xmm2
    addps xmm0, xmm1
    addps xmm0, xmm2
    // calculate d
    movss xmm1, sR
    mulss xmm1, xmm1
    shufps xmm1, xmm1, 0
    subps xmm0, xmm3
    subps xmm1, xmm0
    sqrtps xmm1, xmm1
    // test for intersection
    // at this point:
    // xmm3 = v * v
    // xmm4 = v
    // xmm1 = sqrt(d)
    movaps xmm0, [minus1]  // memory location with { -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0 }
    subps xmm4, xmm1
    // get a mask of d's smaller than 0.0
    psrad xmm1, 31
    // select -1 if less than zero or v*v - d if >= 0
    andps xmm0, xmm1
    andnps xmm1, xmm4
    orps xmm0, xmm1
    ret
}
```

---

Version with intrinsics (only slightly tested - it's compilable and *seems* to generate OK assembly):

```
__m128 intersect4RaysSphere(
     float* rOx, float* rOy, float* rOz,
     float* rVx, float* rVy, float* rVz,
     float sOx, float sOy, float sOz,
     float sR)
{
    __m128 Qx = _mm_sub_ps(_mm_set1_ps(sOx), _mm_load_ps(rOx));
    __m128 Qy = _mm_sub_ps(_mm_set1_ps(sOy), _mm_load_ps(rOy));
    __m128 Qz = _mm_sub_ps(_mm_set1_ps(sOz), _mm_load_ps(rOz));
    __m128 v = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(Qx, _mm_load_ps(rVx)),
               _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(Qy, _mm_load_ps(rVy)),
                          _mm_mul_ps(Qz, _mm_load_ps(rVz))));
    __m128 vsquared = _mm_mul_ps(v, v);
    __m128 lengthQsquared = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(Qx, Qx),
                            _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(Qy, Qy),
                                       _mm_mul_ps(Qz, Qz)));
    __m128 sr = _mm_set1_ps(sR);
    __m128 d = _mm_sub_ps(_mm_mul_ps(sr, sr), _mm_sub_ps(lengthQsquared, vsquared));
    __m128 mask = _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_srai_epi32(_mm_castps_si128(d), 31));
    //__m128 result = _mm_or_ps(_mm_and_ps(_mm_set1_ps(-1.0f), mask),
                              _mm_andnot_ps(mask, _mm_sub_ps(vsquared, d)));
    __m128 result = _mm_or_ps(_mm_and_ps(_mm_set1_ps(-1.0f), mask),
                              _mm_andnot_ps(mask, _mm_sub_ps(v, _mm_sqrt_ps(d))));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Much TNX for answer, i will rethink it (it will take me 2 days at least) ;-) - tryin to run it maybe even more

Comment: @user982377 you're welcome. You can't run this as-is, obviously. I just showed you a better strategy for converting the code to SSE. I'll try to make a version with intrinsics.

Comment: does this automatically calculate without __asm naming?

Comment: @user982377 I converted it to code with intrinsics, you can run this one as-is (but I haven't debugged it).

Comment: It is much harder/slover calculate not only squares but normal length ??- normal length has a simple meaning - and sqrt is AFAIK not so damn slow on modern cpu

Comment: @grungefightr It's still quite slow. And it's completely unnecessary here anyway. Why would you take a square root and then undo it in the next instruction?

Comment: do not understand -value returned from my initial intersect ray sphere function is just distance (and it is later used but i must check it up in code how it is used then) - so it is nice to have it

Comment: @grungefightr oh you mean the result. Well, you just use it to select the nearest sphere, right? It doesn't matter for that purpose whether it's the distance or the square of the distance.

Comment: I looked and i see you meybe are talking about c - indeed the sqrt in length is bad here (mislooked it) , havent noticed it - but as to v*v ald d it is needed ...... REALLY my whole raytracing procedure is about 10 times longer than sample above and it is many more occasions for optymalisation, even in c (will not post it cause it is spaghetti a lot) - but I want to try learn assembly optymalization on such ryatracing example, i want to rewrite it all in asm and check what will be result of it

Comment: @grungefightr I don't see that's it's needed anywhere, the function `f(x) = x*x` is monotonically increasing so it doesn't change the result of the comparison between the distance to the different spheres.

Comment: I know but I would prefer to get proper exact distance (it is simplest later) - compare this distance result not only between spheres but also with bacground plane distance and such is not squared - i do not want such heavy distorted optymizations i want to learn how to write just normal not much luggish assembly - could try such 'degenalisation' tricks on the second step maybe, not now, now i just want proper asm

Comment: @grungefightr very well, there you go, square roots added

Comment: much tnx, nnow i will try to implement it on my prog, (also reading through fpu sse tutorials) will see if it will work, and improve, maybe will back yet, tnx

Answer (score 2):

```
__asm
    {
    movaps xmm0,[float3] //this is vector of yours into xmm0
    mulps xmm0,xmm0       //this is each term squared
    pxor xmm1,xmm1       //clean xmm1 first
    movlhps xmm1,xmm0    //lower 2 terms to the higher 2 parts of xmm1
    addps xmm0,xmm1      //higher 2 terms of xmm0 now has x_square+z_square and  y_square + zero_square
    shufps xmm2,xmm0,0 //we copy y_square to all 4 elements of xmm2
    addps xmm0,xmm2     //now we have sum of all squares in highest of xmm0
    shufps xmm0,xmm0,11111111b // copy result to all 4 parts
    sqrtss xmm0,xmm0           //scalar square-root
    movaps [result],xmm0
    }
```

this may be slower than fully optimized but should be fast enough for vector length calculation. Needs the vector to be aligned-16 byte. Change movaps to movups if you dont want alignment. If you can get this code work, then you can furhter increase performance by putting

```
align 16
```

in the beginning of  movaps xmm0,[float3] to make code also aligned. Then you can check how many bytes each instuction has. Try to reach optimal code-length(multiple of 16 bytes). After sse2(sse3,sse4,avx) there are vertical-horizontal vector instructions which make only 1 instruction to get result.

edited mm0,xmm0 to xmm0,xmm0 at second instruction

here is some list:

http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/simd/sse2.php

Comment: much tnx, i will rethink it and try to fire it up (though can you assure me that it is sse2 only - i had a pentium 4 old machina at home by now) ) It will take a day or two to me ;-)

Comment: i have pentium m which is sse2 and calculates much faster than simple(unoptimized) code in Digital mars.

Comment: sse2: pmaddwd multiples 16bit integers and adds them. For the floating points, i dont know

Comment: I am trying tu understand it but not find what exactly this sse routine is doing - as written in c code - what it is doin exactli :-? Length? have you maybe some for normalize and dot? maybe some tips about writing the ray sphere intersection routine?

Comment: I just showed unoptimized asm code of:                                 inline float length(float3* v) {
     return sqrt( (v->x)*(v->x) + (v->y)*(v->y) + (v->z)*(v->z) );
    }